# node-gyp error while doing npm install

Tags: node.js, pty

I am doing npm install from a project and I am getting this wierd error in node-gyp.

```
> pty.js@0.2.3 install /home/charizard/Open/terminal-codelearn/node_modules/pty.js
> node-gyp rebuild

npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/commander
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/nan
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/tinycolor
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/options
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: "pre" versions of node cannot be installed, use the --nodedir flag instead
gyp ERR! stack     at install (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/install.js:65:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at Object.self.commands.(anonymous function) [as install] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/node-gyp.js:66:37)
gyp ERR! stack     at getNodeDir (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:228:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:110:9
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:659:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:106:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (child_process.js:773:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at Socket.<anonymous> (child_process.js:986:11)
gyp ERR! stack     at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:103:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Pipe.close (net.js:458:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 3.5.0-37-generic
gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/charizard/Open/terminal-codelearn/node_modules/pty.js
gyp ERR! node -v v0.11.8-pre
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.10.10
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! weird error 1
```

When I do npm list, I get this following message.

```
npm ERR! missing: pty.js@>=0.2.2, required by terminal-codelearn@0.0.3
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Sorry, I am completely new to nodejs.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The reason this happens is that `node-gyp` evaluates the `-pre` part of `node@0.11.8-pre` as `-1`. The install then receives a `404` and fails.

```
gyp http GET http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.8.-1/node-v11.8.-1.tar.gz
gyp http 404 http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.8.-1/node-v11.8.-1.tar.gz
```

To solve this problem, use a stable release of Node.js. Otherwise, you need to have the Node source lying around, and use the `--nodedir` flag.

```
npm install --nodedir=/node/src/
```

You can read more about this issue [here](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp/wiki/Error%3A-%22pre%22-versions-of-node-cannot-be-installed).

Answer (score 11):

I solved this by upgrading my version of node to a stable version (e.g. not a "pre" version - your version is 0.8.13-pre) with the following:

```
sudo npm install -g n # install node version manager "n"
sudo n stable # install the latest stable version of node
```

Answer (score 8):

I faced the same problem while installing `node-sass` as well as `windows-build-tools`. I was using `node-v16.2.0`, so it wasn't any `-pre` release. I also updated to the latest version (`node-v16.3.0`) but it did not solve my issue either.

Finally, I solved it by uninstalling the existing version and installing the LTS version (`v14.17.0` at the time of posting).

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. Downgrading to an older version of node version solved the issue. I managed different version of node with nvm. See more details [here](https://www.loginradius.com/blog/engineering/run-multiple-nodejs-version-on-the-same-machine/)

```
nvm list   

    16.10.0
    16.3.0
  * 14.15.0 (Currently using 64-bit executable)
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem while installing `node-sass`:

I solved it by uninstalling `node-sass`:

```
node uninstall node-sass
```

And then install it like this, it will work for you:

```
node install sass --save
```

Answer (score 0):

The node-gyp error is a common issue that occurs during npm install when a package requires a native module to be compiled. This error occurs because the native module needs to be compiled on your local machine, but it requires certain tools and dependencies to be installed.

```
npm install -g node-gyp
```

If these steps do not resolve the issue, you may need to check the package documentation for any additional instructions or contact the package maintainer for support.