# Cannot install node-mapnik on Windows 2008 x64

Tags: windows, node.js, gis, mapnik

I have been spending the last few days trying to get node-mapnik running but with no success.

Initially inspired by Wilhelm Berg's demo (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GlTaRpg3CbQ) which renders pure vector maps using node-mapnik I was interested in getting this running on a Windows Server.

I have worked through all of the StackExchange issues on these topics including Wilhelm's checklist for getting this working on Windows 7 x64 but I am at a dead end and my knowledge is really limited in being able to further diagnose the problem.

My environment is:

- Windows 2008 Server R2 x64
- Visual Studio Express 2012 Desktop Edition (32 & 64 bit)
- Node.js v0.10.26 (64 bit)
- Python27 (32 bit)

I have taken the following steps:

1. Installed Mapnik 2.2.0 SDK downloaded from git and placed in C:\apps\mapnik-v2.2.0
2. Added to PATH:

   C:\apps\mapnik-v2.2.0\lib

   C:\apps\mapnik-v2.2.0\bin
3. Installed Python v2.7 (32bit) downloaded and placed in C:\apps\python27
4. Added to PATH:

   C:\apps\python27

   C:\apps\python27\scripts
5. Added to PYTHONPATH:

   C:\apps\Python27\Lib; C:\apps\Python27\DLLs;

   C:\apps\Python27\Lib\lib-tk;

   C:\apps\mapnik-v2.2.0\python\2.7\site-packages;
6. Rebuild node-gyp using VS 2012

   node-gyp rebuild --msvs_version=2012
7. Downloaded and installed protobuf (32 bit) and placed in c:\apps\protobuf
8. Added to PATH:

   c:\apps\protobuf
9. Installed protobuf using NPM

   npm install protobuf --msvs_version=2012
10. Downloaded Cairo using git

    git clone git://anongit.freedesktop.org/git/cairo
11. Copy Cairo files to mapnik:

    Copy cairo\src\cairo-svg-surface.c to C:\apps\mapnik-v2.2.0\include

    Copy cairo\src\cairo-svg.h to C:\apps\mapnik-v2.2.0\include

    Copy cairo\src\cairo-svg-surface-private.h to C:\apps\mapnik-v2.2.0\include
12. Make proj4 epsg files available:

    SET PROJ_LIB=C:\apps\mapnik-v2.2.0\share\proj
13. Attempt to install node-mapnik

    npm install node-mapnik --msvs_version=2012

I receive the following errors:

> node-pre-gyp ERR! Source compile required: 404 status code downloading
>   tarball ...   mapnik_grid.cpp
>   c:\users\administrator\node_modules\node-mapnik\build\release\obj\global_interm
>   ediate\vector_tile.pb.h(9): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include
>   file: 'googl e/protobuf/stubs/common.h': No such file or directory
>   (C:\Users\Administrator\n
>   ode_modules\node-mapnik\build\Release\obj\global_intermediate\vector_tile.pb.cc
>   )
>   [C:\Users\Administrator\node_modules\node-mapnik\build\mapnik.vcxproj]
>   c:\users\administrator\node_modules\node-mapnik\src\utils.hpp(11):
>   fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'mapnik/unicode.hpp': No
>   such file or director y (..\src\mapnik_geometry.cpp)
>   [C:\Users\Administrator\node_modules\node-mapnik
>   \build\mapnik.vcxproj]   mapnik_layer.cpp   mapnik_cairo_surface.cpp
>   c:\users\administrator\node_modules\node-mapnik\src\mapnik_featureset.hpp(6):
>   f atal error C1083: Cannot open include file:
>   'mapnik/datasource_cache.hpp': No s uch file or directory
>   (..\src\mapnik_featureset.cpp) [C:\Users\Administrator\no
>   de_modules\node-mapnik\build\mapnik.vcxproj]   mapnik_image.cpp
>   C:\Users\Administrator\node_modules\node-mapnik\node_modules\mapnik-vector-tile
>   \src\mapnik3x_compatibility.hpp(4): fatal error C1083: Cannot open
>   include file : 'mapnik/version.hpp': No such file or directory
>   (..\src\mapnik_map.cpp) [C:\U
>   sers\Administrator\node_modules\node-mapnik\build\mapnik.vcxproj]
>   mapnik_datasource.cpp
>   C:\Users\Administrator\node_modules\node-mapnik\node_modules\mapnik-vector-tile
>   \src\mapnik3x_compatibility.hpp(4): fatal error C1083: Cannot open
>   include file : 'mapnik/version.hpp': No such file or directory
>   (..\src\mapnik_color.cpp) [C:
>   \Users\Administrator\node_modules\node-mapnik\build\mapnik.vcxproj]
>   node_mapnik.cpp ..\src\mapnik_grid_view.cpp(9): fatal error C1083:
>   Cannot open include file: 'm apnik/grid/grid.hpp': No such file or
>   directory [C:\Users\Administrator\node_mo
>   dules\node-mapnik\build\mapnik.vcxproj]   mapnik_projection.cpp
>   C:\Users\Administrator\node_modules\node-mapnik\node_modules\mapnik-vector-tile
>   \src\mapnik3x_compatibility.hpp(4): fatal error C1083: Cannot open
>   include file : 'mapnik/version.hpp': No such file or directory
>   (..\src\mapnik_layer.cpp) [C:
>   \Users\Administrator\node_modules\node-mapnik\build\mapnik.vcxproj]
>   mapnik_feature.cpp ..\src\mapnik_grid.cpp(9): fatal error C1083:
>   Cannot open include file: 'mapnik /version.hpp': No such file or
>   directory [C:\Users\Administrator\node_modules\n
>   ode-mapnik\build\mapnik.vcxproj]   mapnik_palette.cpp
>   ..\src\mapnik_image_view.cpp(11): fatal error C1083: Cannot open
>   include file: 'mapnik/color.hpp': No such file or directory
>   [C:\Users\Administrator\node_modu
>   les\node-mapnik\build\mapnik.vcxproj]   mapnik_vector_tile.cpp
>   c:\users\administrator\node_modules\node-mapnik\src\utils.hpp(11):
>   fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'mapnik/unicode.hpp': No
>   such file or director y (..\src\mapnik_cairo_surface.cpp)
>   [C:\Users\Administrator\node_modules\node-m
>   apnik\build\mapnik.vcxproj]   mapnik_expression.cpp
>   mapnik_memory_datasource.cpp ..\src\mapnik_memory_datasource.cpp(3):
>   fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'mapnik/version.hpp': No
>   such file or directory [C:\Users\Administrator\n
>   ode_modules\node-mapnik\build\mapnik.vcxproj]
>   c:\users\administrator\node_modules\node-mapnik\src\utils.hpp(11):
>   fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'mapnik/unicode.hpp': No
>   such file or director y (..\src\mapnik_feature.cpp)
>   [C:\Users\Administrator\node_modules\node-mapnik\
>   build\mapnik.vcxproj] ..\src\mapnik_image.cpp(7): fatal error C1083:
>   Cannot open include file: 'mapni k/color.hpp': No such file or
>   directory [C:\Users\Administrator\node_modules\no
>   de-mapnik\build\mapnik.vcxproj]
>   C:\Users\Administrator\node_modules\node-mapnik\node_modules\mapnik-vector-tile
>   \src\mapnik3x_compatibility.hpp(4): fatal error C1083: Cannot open
>   include file : 'mapnik/version.hpp': No such file or directory
>   (..\src\mapnik_datasource.cpp )
>   [C:\Users\Administrator\node_modules\node-mapnik\build\mapnik.vcxproj]
>   C:\Users\Administrator\node_modules\node-mapnik\node_modules\mapnik-vector-tile
>   \src\mapnik3x_compatibility.hpp(4): fatal error C1083: Cannot open
>   include file : 'mapnik/version.hpp': No such file or directory
>   (..\src\mapnik_projection.cpp )
>   [C:\Users\Administrator\node_modules\node-mapnik\build\mapnik.vcxproj]
>   C:\Users\Administrator\node_modules\node-mapnik\node_modules\mapnik-vector-tile
>   \src\mapnik3x_compatibility.hpp(4): fatal error C1083: Cannot open
>   include file : 'mapnik/version.hpp': No such file or directory
>   (..\src\mapnik_palette.cpp) [
>   C:\Users\Administrator\node_modules\node-mapnik\build\mapnik.vcxproj]
>   C:\Users\Administrator\node_modules\node-mapnik\node_modules\mapnik-vector-tile
>   \src\mapnik3x_compatibility.hpp(4): fatal error C1083: Cannot open
>   include file : 'mapnik/version.hpp': No such file or directory
>   (..\src\node_mapnik.cpp) [C:\
>   Users\Administrator\node_modules\node-mapnik\build\mapnik.vcxproj]
>   c:\users\administrator\node_modules\node-mapnik\src\utils.hpp(11):
>   fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'mapnik/unicode.hpp': No
>   such file or director y (..\src\mapnik_vector_tile.cpp)
>   [C:\Users\Administrator\node_modules\node-map
>   nik\build\mapnik.vcxproj]

Comment: possible duplicate of [node-gyp error while doing npm install](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18777882/node-gyp-error-while-doing-npm-install)

Answer (score 0):

node-mapnik now ships with windows binaries, so none of the above steps should be needed. See https://github.com/mapnik/node-mapnik#installing for details.